# Sharing custom content based on target

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I am implementing "sharing" feature for WP8.1 XAML app. Is that possible to customize the content based on the the target? 
For example, if I want to share the texts in Twitter it will share different texts from Facebook or email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's not possible. Once you show share UI, the data request event is fired and data is generated before the user chooses the app.

If you are interested what user has chosen, you can try with [TargetApplicationChosen event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.datatransfermanager.targetapplicationchosen.aspx), which should allow you to get the name of choosen app. Nevertheless it's after the data is genereted, so this can be used when preparing default data for future requests.